# Trying to align radio buttons in RadioGroups in compound layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout fragment.  Why aren't the two radio groups aligned?  I've tried with and without margin and padding in the `RadioGroup`.

I'm assuming that `marginLeft` is measured from the left edge of the radio button itself and `marginRight` is measured from the right of the longest radio button caption.  The documentation is not clear in this respect.

Note that I've deleted any lines not related to layout (e.g. text).  All text sizes are `15sp`.

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lengthImage"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/length"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lengthImage"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioGroup
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/lengthMetres"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/lengthFeet"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/distanceImage"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/distance"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/distanceImage"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioGroup
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/distanceMile"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/distanceKM"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/distanceNM"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[EDIT]

Solution.

Hard coding the RadioGroup widths to 100dp works perfectly.  I hate doing this though.  I bet there's a combination of resolution, density and orientation out there that will break this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fully build your layout without hard coding the `100dp`.

By making few tricks with `android:layout_alignLeft`, `android:layout_alignBottom` and `android:layout_alignTop` you can solve your problem with the `RadioGroups`.

But, you will have to change the XML a little bit, because it will work only if both `RadioGroups` are in the same `RelativeLayout`.

This is your code with all adjustments:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lengthMetres"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="metres" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lengthFeet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="feet" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lengthImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/radio_group_1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio_group_1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/radio_group_1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio_group_1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lengthImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/length" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/radio_group_1"
        android:layout_below="@id/radio_group_1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/distanceMile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="mile" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/distanceKM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="km" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/distanceNM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="NM" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lengthImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/radio_group_2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio_group_2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/radio_group_2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/radio_group_2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lengthImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/length" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: Aligned Radio Groups]

I think, that this solution in your specific case is applicable, but for some kind of generic solution, when you have more then two RadioGroups this solution will have to be improved.

Hope this approach could be useful for you :)

Comment: Thank you.  Just wanted to let you know that I like this approach.  It will take me a couple of days to get tie to try it but I'll let you know.  I will adapt it since I have 8 groups but that should be easy enough.

Comment: Great, if you find that for 8 groups it doesn't fit, then we can try to improve it. I am pretty sure that there is a solution for N groups. Will glad to know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"`(not android:marginLeft) for your RadioGroups.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lengthImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lengthImage"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="length" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lengthMetres"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="meters" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lengthFeet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="feets" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/distanceImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/distanceImage"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="distance" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/distanceMile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="foo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/distanceKM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="boo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/distanceNM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="moo" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent"` - do you mean in The RadioGroups?

Comment: Thanks Lecho.  match_parent doesn't work, since the RadioGroup will then use the full width of the parent RelativeLayout.  However, it did get me thinking about the problem and it is indeed the width causing it.  The solution for me was to hard code 100dp.  The layout is now perfect.  Tested on multiple resolutions and densities.  I can't really mark the answer as correct, since it doesn't fix the problem, so +1 for your time and kicking off another chain of thought.  Thanks!

Comment: PS.  The margin thing was a typo.  I edited my question to avoid folks saying "you need margin, not padding" and forgot the layout_.